# Content Security Policy blocks Data

Tags: django, content-security-policy

My content security policy IMG-SRC keeps blocking images 'data:image/png;base64...' and I don't know where they are coming from.

I use report-uri to manage my CSP reports, and it allows you to ignore any reports beginning with 'data:...', but it says "Only enable this filter if you are sure you understand what this means."

Can anyone help me understand what this means, and where these data images would be coming from?

UPDATE: Here is the full report as shown in the console:

my-sitecom/:1 Refused to load the image 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com".

Comment: Please post the full CPI violation report.

Comment: Have you tried searching your source code for `data:image` and similar? What software are we talking about? Are you installing a lot of 3rd party dependencies, using a CMS, etc.?

Comment: @markus Thanks for the reply! I edited the post to include the full report. data:image is not in my source code. No CMS, very few third party dependencies. And everything seems to still load correctly even when data:image is blocked. Another oddity, this problem sometimes only shows up for me on my staging site. Not on development or production.

Comment: It sounds like you have some JavaScript which is trying to create 'data:' URLs — probably some third-party JavaScript from one of the sources your policy allows. You basically don’t want to be using any JavaScript that creates such 'data:' URLs, because as far as XSS risks go, they’re essentially just as much of a risk as allowing 'unsafe-inline'. And there’s no way in CSP to allow only certain kinds of 'data:' URLs (e.g., no way to only allow 'data:' URLs for images while disallowing other media types) — nor is there any way to only allow 'data:' URLs from a particular source.